# How and when to declare a Main Method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans, program-entry-point

This may seem like a stupid queestion to most of you, but I have been learning Java using BlueJ, and BlueJ is created for learning, and as such Main Methods are not necessary given the BlueJ extensions provided by my University.

Therefore, now that I am playing around in both NetBeans and IntelliJ - I really want to get a good idea of when to declare a Main Method.

I know the Main method is the entry point of a package when it is compiled and run. But that is the extent of my knowledge.

If I am to build some apps in a full blown IDE, should I place all of my Class methods within a Main Method? Should the Main method be seperate from all others? Do I declare instance Variables within the Main Method?

Are there any good sites, or tutorial materials available that can help me structure my BlueJ Java knowledge into an IDE that requires a Main Method?

Thanks

Comment: If you learned java without ever using a `main`-method that surely was not a good way to learn it. I would recommend just starting with a tutorial somewhere. You don't seem to be too far into the whole topic so just starting over and skipping the parts you already know are probably a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

Main method is an entry point to your application.

If you watch any Java related tutorial, you'll probably see something like this.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

This has been taken from Oracle's website.

When working with IntelliJ, you'll be presented with a `package main` on the top, or something else.

You see. Java unlike some other languages distinguish between namespaces using those packages. Think of them as a little packages full of Java classes that you can reuse.

For example, if you look at Log4J's repo => [here](https://github.com/apache/log4j/tree/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j), all these folders are essentially  packages.

That way you can have many packages, and a single file that will trigger your main method, and start everything else.

That's how it's usually done.

But if you really want to learn Java from scratch. My suggestion is go to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBWX97e1E9g&list=PLE7E8B7F4856C9B19). Derek has done some marvelous job with his tutorials.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

While technically you can have more than one `main` method, for most use cases you only need one.

You should define it where it makes sense to do so in some "central" class responsible for bootstrapping your application and getting everything going.

The `main` method is `static` though so it can't access your class' instance. Typically this is how you'd get around this.

```
class TicTacToe {

  public void theEntryPointToYourApplication() {
    // ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This doesn't necessarily have to be the same class where you 
    // defined your main method
    TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();
    ticTacToe.theEntryPointToYourApplication();
  }

}
```

This is just a small example though there are many ways and different approaches depending on your specific use case and needs.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have never used BlueJ.I've always been a netbeans fan.But the answer to your question is a general rule that most of the Object Oriented Programming Languages follow.You know that main method is the entry point of a package when it is compiled and run.Let me explain it in simple language.

Consider a soccer game.Assume that the field is the main method.The players are different functions.You are free to define any number of functions, but only 22 functions are called in the field.The whole game is controlled and played by these 22 functions only.So what do you learn from this?

We learn that java is only concerned with what is present in its main method just like the fans sitting in the stadium are only concerned with the 22 players who are currently playing.So if a programmer is writing a small program,normally the whole logic goes into the main method.But if its a large program,the program is distributed into various modules/functions and then these functions are called in the main method so that they get executed.